# How to open web page in web view on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, webview

I want to open web page on the `webView` by passing the web url of that page. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can load a website using this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.wrightscs.com"]]];
```

You can also load HTML into a UIWebView using this:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<strong>It Work's!</strong>" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```